# Function that receives iterators and returns vector

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I was given a task to create a function identical to the following

```
template <typename It>
auto MakeSet(It range_begin, It range_end) {
     return set(range_begin, range_end);
}
```

But it must be a template that receives iterators (begin() and end()) and returns a vector with the element's from the range.

I tried

```
template<typename Type, typename It>
auto MakeVector(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    return vector<Type> v(range_begin, range_end);
}
```

However I get the following error

> unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Comment: Can't you simply replace `set` with `vector`? Are you using C++17?

Comment: Don't name the variable `v` in the return statement, same to the `set` example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the element's type from iterator, and specify it as template argument for `std::vector`.

```
template <typename It>
auto MakeVector(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    return std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type>(range_begin, range_end);
}
```

Since C++17, with the help of [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides) you can just

```
template <typename It>
auto MakeVector(It range_begin, It range_end) {
    return std::vector(range_begin, range_end);
}
```